# ZipException when attempting to open jar file

Tags: java, jar

I keep getting a `java.util.zip.ZipException` when I try to open a jar file. I was able to reproduce the issue with the following stripped-down bit of code (ignore the weird `populateSamples()` method name):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.populateSamples();
    }

    private void populateSamples() {
        JarFile jf = null;
        try {
            String s = new File(this.getClass().getResource("Test.class").getPath()).getParent().replaceAll("(!|file:\\\\)", "");
            jf = new JarFile(s);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                jf.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is the exception I get:

```
$ java -jar EclipseTest.jar
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:128)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:136)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:73)
at Test.populateSamples(Test.java:40)
at Test.main(Test.java:17)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Test.populateSamples(Test.java:54)
at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

I can list the contents of the jar file with `jar tf` just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `s` is not null? The expression that sets `s` has a lot of scope for getting a null value in there somewhere...

Comment: Thank you. It was not null, but the construct passed to the `replaceAll()` method was faulty, so the string was still beginning with "file:".

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem. The `replaceAll("(!|file:\\\\)", "");` bit was not working as expected as the "file:" bit was not being replaced. I shall now embark on a quest to figure out why not, and complete this answer.